# Why does my Flutter aps pubspec.yaml looks totally different?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm just trying to include an external font but all other examples on the web have a different pubspec.yaml file. I have attached a snapshot of the file I have.

**My pubspe.yaml snapshot**
[image]

Comment: open with any other text editor other than AndroidStudio. This happens many times due to the wrong file format and encoding.

Comment: I saw it in my project earlier. It happened for pasting by holding a special key like ctrl,shift,alt. I didn't know what happened ! I just undo by click ctrl+z !

Comment: this is the bug in android studio close all the projects from android studio and then go to C:\Users\<username>\.android and find .caches folder and delete this folder again try to restart your project